# Best resource for exoplanet statistics?

Tags: exoplanet, data-analysis, modeling

While the number of detected exoplanets is still low, is there a model that, considering the number and duration of made observations, and the fact that (non)detections depend on orbital plane alignment and timing, can answer questions like

- what is the typical number of exoplanets for a star?
- what percentage of extrasolar systems can be expected to have at least one exoplanet?
- how many (Jupiter, Earth)-like planets do we expect in each solar system?
- which types of stars tend to have which types of planets?

Comment: Can you clarify what your looking for ? Is it more statistics on detected exoplanets to date, for which [NASA Exoplanet Archive](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/) is the best bet or a model of exoplanet formation and numbers per star etc or a model for how many exoplanet detections there should be ?

Comment: You seem to be looking for keywords like "completeness correction" and "detection bias correction". Try searching for those.

Comment: @astrosnapper Good question and link - I'm looking for a model of exoplanet formation and numbers per star that takes existing (non)detections and their probabilities into account

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape These are excellent terms! A model that would employ these is what I'm looking for

Comment: Model and statistics are different things. This question is at least on the border of too broad imho. You are asking for a review paper on explanation research and observations